# FTP or HTTP for large file uploads?

Tags: php, http, ftp

I am debating whether to use FTP or HTTP for large file upload and downloads. File uploads will consists of text and audio files, from a range of a couple of KB - 200MB. I have a couple of questions, such as:

1. Which would be faster? HTTP or FTP
2. Which would be more reliable?
3. Which would be of greater ease and convenience for the end user?
4. What other alternatives are there for larger file uploads.

Note: I need to somehow keep track of what files what users upload.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion File transfers which are part of a website navigation should use the same protocol, as switching protocol may require additional work on your server, and it will open a new connection.
Moreover, HTTP supports POST and PUT methods which are designed for that goal.

If you simply want to upload files, then FTP is the dedicated protocol, but it may not be implemented on all web browser.

Comment: Which browsers support FTP uploads?  I know most support FTP downloads.

Comment: That should exists, even I never tested out. I prefer to use a separate ftp client.

Comment: You can use PHP to connect to an FTP server and upload files using [`ftp_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)

Comment: @Indranil I think the question is about client to server upload. To execute your PHP you would have to already load the web page.

Comment: I think I am going to try a java based solution for the upload.